# ASMX Web Service Problem Communicating with Windows Service In a Separate Thread

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-7, asmx

There is a Windows Service on Windows Server 2003 (Amazon Virtual Machine). Some applications can communicate with it (using pipes, but there is an wrapper to do it). It is tested and it  works. Also, there is a Web Service written in C# (ASP.NET) which communicates with mentioned  Windows Service. When Web Method is called, it creates an instance of the class and calls a function - the function "connects" to Windows Service and post a job to it. But, if inside Web Method is created a thread and the function which "connects" to Windows Service is called inside a thread - connection fails. Connection to Windows Service uses pipes. Web Service works on IIS7. It is worth to mention that all works on my local machine, either from debugger (local server started by VS 2010) or from IE when I call Web Method on Web Service which works on local IIS7. In local all works - but on Amazon Instance doesn't. I'm not a web programmer, so I think there is some issue with security. Any hint? Thanks.

EDIT: Uwe's comment reminded me - the Web Method at first tries to download some files using http and it saves them to path C:\intetpub\wwwroot\files\". It works if files are downloaded from the web method, but download fails if it is done from another thread created in Web Method. Exception was: Access is denied. So, I changed security settings on mentioned folder and explicitly allowed user created by IIS7 (IIS_IUSRS) to read/write the folder, and now files can be downloaded. It seems that the source of these problems is the same.

EDIT: The solution is moved to an answer on Will's suggestion.

Comment: Can you post details, how "connection fails" actually behaves? I.e. detailled error message, stack trace, behaviour, etc.

Comment: How connection fails is not relevant, since the "connection" is function call. The problem is: I can communicate to the windows service from the web service, if the communication is from the same thread in which executes Web Method; if Web Method creates a new thread - communication fails. I have no more details received from mentioned Windows Service. Since it is work from the same thread on Amazon Virtual Machine, and not if threads are different, and also it works on my local computer even with different threads, I thought that it is something related to security or permissions. Thanks.

Comment: @Vladimir: if how the connection fails is not relevant, why not pretend that it doesn't fail at all? Of course it's relevant.

Comment: @John, thanks for the post. But, there is some other problem; as I said "the connection" is just a function call. It was something about security context, and finally I found the problem: the thread created in Web Method does not have the same security context, so I had to obtain it in Web Method: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity wi = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); and pass it to the new thread. So, obviously I didn't formulate my question on the right way. Now, the problem is solved and this question can be closed. Thanks again.

Comment: @Vladimir: if you had posted more detail to your question, then you could have posted your solution as an answer. I would have upvoted it, and it would have been useful for others with the same problem.

Comment: @John, you're right. I added a solution at the end of the question, so it might be useful for somebody who has the same problem.

Comment: @Vlad please remove the solution from the question and put it in an answer.  Yes, you're answering your own question, and that seems odd, but that's the acceptable way to handle this situation.  Thanks.

Comment: @Will - sorry for delay; a solution is written as an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys, the solution is found and as Will recomends, I'll post it here, as an answer to my own question. So, the solution:

The problem was because the thread created by Web Method has to be impersonated. So, in the caller method I had to something like:

```
[WebMethod]
public void Fnc()
{
    ...
    ...
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity wi =    System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    System.Threading.Thread postJobThread = new Thread(PostJobThread);
    postJobThread.Start(wi);
    ...
}

...

private void PostJobThread(object ob)
{
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity wi = (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)ob;
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = wi.Impersonate();

    ...
    // Do some job which couldn't be done in this thread
    ...
    // OK, job is finished
    if(ctx != null)
    ctx.Undo();
}
```

That's all. Thanks to guys who commented my question and I hope it'll be useful for somebody else.